# Are these vectors linearly independent? 3 vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this vector set S = {(2,-1,2), (1,0,3), (3,-2,1)}. Are they linearly independent?

$$(0, 0, 0) = c_1(2,-1,2) + c_2(1,0,3) + c_3(3,-2,1)$$

Here are the corresponding equations:

$$2c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3= 0$$
$$-c_1 - 2c_3 = 0$$
$$2c_1 + + 3c_2 + c_3 = 0$$

->

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$-> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.5 & 1.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $c_3 = t, c_2 = t, c_1 = -2t$

So, there are infinite non-trivial solutions and as a result the vectors are linearly dependent. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, you should improve your wording and write complete sentences.

Comment: Just a tip but in general, you can do this faster by just checking if the matrix of your vectors is invertible by using the determinant

Comment: With some more experience you’ll be able to spot that the third vector is equal to $2$ times the first minus the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your work is correct.

You may as well check the determinant of your matrix to see if it is zero in which case the vectors are dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't use matrices for a simple set of equations like these.  You have 
$2c_1+ c_2+ 3c_3= 0$
$-c_1- 2c_3= 0$
$2c_1+ 3c_2+ c_3= 0$

From the second equation $c_1= -2c_3$.  So the first equation is $-4c_3+ c_2+ 3c_3= c_2- c_3= 0$ and the second is 
$-4c_3+ 3c_2+ c_3= 3c_2- 3c_3= 0$.

Both of those equations give $c_2= c_3$ so, yes, there are an infinite number of solutions and these vectors are dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough rep. But I just want to say that you have shown these vectors to be linearly *dependent*. At the end of your question you write **in**depdenent. This might just be a typo, but it is worth making sure.

**These vectors are linearly *dependent***. Your working proves there are infinitely many choices of $c_1, c_2, c_3$ which form solutions to the equation. Just one such solution would imply these vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: great catch and thnaks! careless error